# tengo una aplicacion en express hosteada en Cpanel y da un error en la ruta "citas/pago". Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: nodejs, cpanel

> "citas/pago" es la ruta que da error 404 en cPanel

```javascript
    app.set("view engine", "ejs");
    app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "/views"));
    app.use('/citas/public',  express.static(process.cwd()  + '/public'))
```

> La ruta "/citas/" si funciona

```
    app.get("/citas/", (req, res) => {
      res.render("index", { titulo: "My page" });
    });
```

> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

```
    app.get("/citas/pago/", (req, res) => {
      res.render("pago", { titulo: "My page" });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Revisa la versión de Node en CPANEl ya que siempre son versiones antiguas no permiten hacer muchas operaciones y codigos, te recomiendo subir tu app en heroku o en contenedores, por lo general la versión de Node en Cpanel es la 12 y es obsoleta para muchas cosas.

Saludos.

Comment: La version mas reciente en Cpanel es la version 12.22.9. Gracias.